# Documentation: duplicate topics shown but it's the same record

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

So I encountered this when browsing the documentation topics for `VB.NET`:

[image: Dupe]

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/topics?page=2&tab=popular)

Additional detail (dunno if it would help): I was the other editor in the second topic.

The first topic looks fine to me:

[image: dupe2]

However, the second one prompts me to edit once I opened the said topic.:

[image]

I didn't took any actions in the second one since I thought it might cause some more issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They sure do look identical, but they are actually two different topics. One has id 7483, and the other is 7484. Since the latter had an edit applied to it since it was created, I deleted 7483.

As for the edit getting loaded up... you have a [draft in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/drafts/88662). Note that it applies to topic 7483, so if you submit it, it'll put the topic I just deleted back. :) So, the best thing to do here is for you to go and "discard" the draft.

Comment: Ohh.. okay. I went back to the topic. Nothing to discard now and the edit is there. :)

Comment: @CrushSundae Maybe! I'm not sure how we ended up with two identical topics created a minute apart... there may be something lurking there. Could also just be a weird one-off. I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow... I wonder if it's something dumb like someone double-clicking "Approve" on a proposed change.

Comment: I dunno if this would help but something happened during my edit of the topic. It already got approved. But upon checking it again, the edit is not there. Then I re-done the edit, then it happened to be saved there now. Also, I just noticed this today (which is more likely weeks apart already from the edit). I think this dupe is not there before.